# Logged in Username on WordPress page

Tags: php, wordpress

I need currently Logged in Username in my WordPress Page ( HTML, JS). There must a standard function of php that I can call?
In header I can see uid , that can be used to fetch the username?

Comment: Check docs. Wp_user().  Also ur question is vague with no code.  U can output it to ur html or u can hook it to a js object.

Comment: i am bit new to wordpress world, no idea how to call wp_user from within javascript. All i need to display username in my wordpress page HTML

Comment: You can use wp_get_current_user()->user_login to get logged in username and wp_get_current_user() object for more information. To display it in js you need to localize script and pass from your functions.php to js file.

Comment: Go to your theme file, find the the header. And just hard code it with wp_get_current_user()->user_login.  Not the best way to do it on WordPress. But will get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following peice of code to print the firstname of loggedin user.

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) 
{     
    global $current_user; 
    get_currentuserinfo();    
    echo $current_user->user_firstname;    
}
```

Comment: @Trisup you mean I should write this in js file?

Comment: You are using JavaScript?

Comment: I want to make this change only on UI HTML JS page @Trisup

Comment: Then you need to pass the value to JS file using localized script.

Comment: No idea what that JS localized script will be.

Comment: You can read it from here, https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script

Comment: It actually helps you to send value from php file to js file. Its a WordPress predefined function work with wp_enqueue_script method.